# None connected graphs for n=59?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, curated-data

For some reason

```
GraphData["Connected", 59]
```

gives no graphs, is this a bug?

Comment: Please do not add the `bugs` tag to your own posts.  [The agreement is that it should be added by someone else once it is confirmed by the community.](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/354/how-should-the-bug-tag-be-used)

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not a bug.  [`GraphData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphData.html) is a *non-exhaustive* collection of useful and common graphs.  It does not and could not possibly include all graphs.

`GraphData["Connected", n]` will return all connected `n`-vertex graphs *from this particular database*, but it does not return *all* connected `n`-vertex graphs.